# How to make a kernel function which callable from both the host and device?

Tags: cuda

The following trial presents my intention, which failed to compile:

```
__host__ __device__ void f(){}

int main()
{
    f<<<1,1>>>();
}
```

The compiler complaints:

```
a.cu(5): error: a __device__ function call cannot be configured

1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00001537_00000000-6_a.cpp1.ii".
```

Hope my statement is clear, and thanks for advices.

Comment: Surely you mean `__device__ __host__ void f(){}`?

Comment: I tried both "__device__ __host__" and "__host__ __device__" combination, and both failed

Comment: The above code was based on a tutorial "http://www.uni-graz.at/~liebma/CUDA/NVISION08-Getting_Started_with_CUDA.pdf"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to create a CUDA kernel entry point, e.g. `__global__` function. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__host__ __device__ void f() {
#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__
    printf ("Device Thread %d\n", threadIdx.x);
#else
    printf ("Host code!\n");
#endif
}

__global__ void kernel() {
   f();
}

int main() {
   kernel<<<1,1>>>();
   if (cudaDeviceSynchronize() != cudaSuccess) {
       fprintf (stderr, "Cuda call failed\n");
   }
   f();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: __CUDA_ARCH__ will be defined in both calls. Pre-compiler code makes no sense in this context...

Comment: @HenriqueMendonça: I [believe you are mistaken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16073481/1593077).

Answer (score -2):

The tutorial you are looking at is so old, 2008? It might not be compatible with the version of CUDA you are using.

You can use `__global__` and that means `__host__ __device__`, this works:

```
__global__ void f()
{
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
}

int main()
{
    f<<<1,1>>>();
}
```

Comment: `__global__` specifies a kernel entry point, i.e. a function that will auto-parallelize into GPU code when called with launch parameters.  `__host__` and `__device__` are not used to decorate kernel functions.  The only sense in which you could say `__global__` means `__host__ __device__` with any sense is in the case of [cuda dynamic parallelism](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-dynamic-parallelism/index.html), which is only available on cc 3.5 devices.  Even in that case, I think it's sloppy to say `__global__` means `__host__ __device__`

Comment: @RobertCrovella I agree, I only meant they are equivalent in his context, as my code cannot be called from the host anyway as it has kernel variables.