# Questions about CUDA macro __CUDA_ARCH__

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, cuda, cuda-gdb

I have a simple cuda code in `ttt.cu`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
__global__ void example(){
   printf("__CUDA_ARCH__: %d \n", __CUDA_ARCH__);
}
int main(){
example<<<1,1>>>();
}
```

with CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(Hello)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

cuda_add_executable(sss ttt.cu)
```

Then I got the error: `identifier "__CUDA_ARCH__" is undefined`. I would like to know why does this happen and what should I do for making the `__CUDA_ARCH__` valid? And can we use valid `__CUDA_ARCH__` in host code within a header `.h` file?

Update:

I intended to use the following cmake for generating a 750 cuda arch, however,  this always results in a `__CUDA_ARCH__` = 300 (2080 ti with cuda 10.1). I tried both `set_property` and `target_compile_options`, which all failed.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(Hello)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
cuda_add_executable(oounne ttt.cu)
set_property(TARGET oounne PROPERTY CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 75)
#target_compile_options(oounne PRIVATE  $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-gencode 
arch=compute_75,code=sm_75>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__CUDA_ARCH__` is a *compiler macro*.

> can we use valid `__CUDA_ARCH__` in host code

No, it is [intended to be used in device code only](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#virtual-architecture-macros):

> The host code (the non-GPU code) must not depend on it.

You cannot print a compiler macro the way you are imagining.  It is not an ordinary numerical variable defined in C++.  You could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637392/c-preprocessor-expand-macro-in-a-warning) but that would print at compile-time, not at run-time.

To print at run-time, you could do something like this:

```
$ cat t2.cu
#include <cstdio>
#define STR_HELPER(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_HELPER(x)

__device__ void print_arch(){
  const char my_compile_time_arch[] = STR(__CUDA_ARCH__);
  printf("__CUDA_ARCH__: %s\n", my_compile_time_arch);
}
__global__ void example()
{
   print_arch();
}

int main(){

example<<<1,1>>>();
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t2 t2.cu

$ ./t2
__CUDA_ARCH__: 520
$
```

Note that there are quite a few questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcuda%5D++__CUDA_ARCH__) on the `cuda` tag discussing `__CUDA_ARCH__`, you may wish to review some of them.

Comment: Is not the whole given question a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072740/the-behavior-of-cuda-arch-macro, which you have answered?

Comment: The question you linked does not explain how to print it out.

Comment: I have a problem reproducing your code with CMAKE, Could you please take a look at my update?

Comment: Sorry, I won't be able to help with cmake.  There are lots and lots of cmake questions on the `cuda` tag, and you can always ask a new question.