# __CUDA__ undefined when running nvcc in for a .cu file

Tags: c++, cuda, nvcc

I am trying to compile a .cu file which includes a .cuh file with a templated device function using nvcc. That same .cuh file is also included from a .cpp, so I am trying to prevent the templated device function to be visible from the .cpp side. To do so I am using

foo.cuh

```
#if defined(__CUDA__) && defined(__CUDA_ARCH__)

template <typename T>
__device__ void foo(){...}
#endif
```

However, when I try to use the device function from a kernel, it says the function doesn't exist while compiling the .cu. The .cu compiles fine if I remove the `__CUDA__` check, but in that case it fails later, when compiling the .cpp file.

Am I missing something in the check?

Comment: I thoguht there was a __CUDA__. __CUDACC__ means compiling with nvcc, host and device mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `__CUDA__` macro defined by [nvcc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#nvcc-identification-macro).  Therefore, unless you defined it somewhere using your own methodology (?) your `#if` directive will always be skipped.

Perhaps you want `__CUDACC__`?

example:

```
$ cat test.cuh
#ifdef __CUDACC__
__device__ void foo(){};
#endif

void f();

$ cat main.cpp
#include <test.cuh>

int main(){
  f();
}
$ cat test.cu
#include <test.cuh>
__global__ void k(){foo();}

void f(){

  k<<<1,1>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -I. -o test test.cu main.cpp
$ g++  -I. -c main.cpp
$ nvcc -I. -o test test.cu main.o
$ compute-sanitizer ./test
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

(the `__CUDA_ARCH__` [macro](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#virtual-architecture-macros) is [not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072740/the-behavior-of-cuda-arch-macro) here either.)